# How do i access a list thats defined in a different script?

Tags: list, unity-game-engine, global-variables

So on `managerino.cs` I have the following code:

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class managerino : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool[] availablecardSlots; //the lenght of the list is set on the inspector and all the values begin as true
}
```

And on my `DragDrop.cs` script (note that the scripts are not applied to the same gameObject) I want to set one of the elements in `availablecardSlots` to false, which means I have to be able to modify the list outside of the script where it was created.

I tried this:

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class DragDrop : MonoBehaviour
{
    int n = 2;
    private void Start()
    {
        managerino = FindObjectOfType<managerino>;
    }

    managerino.availablecardSlots[n] = true;
    Destroy(gameObject);
```

But its not working I'm getting three errors all about managerino

Answer (score 0):

Because you can not write commands in the body of the class. Move the commands into the method, also you forget `()` after `GetComponent`.

```cs
private void Start()
{
    managerino = FindObjectOfType<managerino>();
    managerino.availablecardSlots[n] = true;
    Destroy(gameObject);
}
```